# How to identify the grid in kendo spreadsheet Grid using selenium c#

Tags: selenium, spreadsheet, kendo-ui-grid

I am not able to find the  element in kedo grid. I have to identify the grid , using that grid i have to identify the cells and enter value in them. but i m not able to identify the grid itself.

Below is the xpath.

```
 IWebElement testoj = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='pricingTableSpreadsheet']"));
```

if i run this xpath in console it returns the element but wen I run this through code it does not detect the element

HTML

```
<div id="secContainer">
 <div kendo-splitter="" k-panes="[null, { collapsible: true, collapsed: true, min: '235px', size: '235px' }]" k-orientation="'vertical'" id="k-splitter" style="height: 100%; border: 0 solid transparent;" data-role="splitter" class="k-widget k-splitter">
  <div role="group" class="k-pane k-scrollable" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 92px; width: 1066px;">
   <div ui-view="prdTableView" class="fullHeight ng-scope">
    <div ui-view="wipprdView" class="fullHeight ng-scope">
     <div style="positi on:absolute; left: 5px; z-index: 900;  padding-top: 2px;"></div>
     <div style="position:absolute; float: right; right: 5px; z-index: 900;">
     </div>
     <div kendo-spreadsheet="" id="pricingTableSpreadsheet" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-top: -3px; margin-left: -2px;" k-options="ptSpreadOptions" k-scope-field="spreadsheet" class="noFormula k-widget k-spreadsheet" data-role="spreadsheet">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>        
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: may be your grid is inside the frame/iframe

Comment: @Murthi i added the html code, its not a iframe

Comment: may be you need to wait for the element to appear on the page.